# React nasty bug ,which I cant figure out

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React ,trying to develop a Quiz with questions,I have Quiz component which recieve array which is Json with the questions. This is the Quiz class :

```
class Quiz extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      questions: this.props.jsonArray,
      score: 0,
      currentQuest: 0,
      guessedAnswer:'',
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    console.log("In parent submited");
    let correct_answer= this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuest].correct_answer;
    console.log("Correct answer is " + correct_answer);
    if(this.state.guessedAnswer===correct_answer){
      console.log('Correct answer');
      this.setState({score : this.state.score + 1});
    }
    console.log('Your score is ' + this.state.score);
    this.setState({currentQuest : this.state.currentQuest + 1});
    console.log("Current question is " + this.state.currentQuest);

  }

  handleChange(val){

    this.setState({guessedAnswer: val});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.currentQuest< this.state.questions.length ? <QuestComp question={this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuest]} onChangeValue={this.handleChange} onFormSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/> :null}
      </div>
    );

  }

}
```

It calls the Question component with parameter ,the current question ,here is the Question component :

```
class QuestComp extends Component{


  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      question: this.props.question,
      rerender: false
    }
    console.log('In constructor in question');
  }

  updateAnswer=(e)=>{
    console.log('changed ' + e.target.value);
    this.props.onChangeValue(e.target.value);
  }
  submitForm=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({question : this.props.question});
    this.props.onFormSubmit(e);
  }


  render(){
    console.log("Rerender child" + this.props.question.question);
    let incorrect_answers=[];
    for(let i=0;i<this.state.question.incorrect_answers.length;i++){
      incorrect_answers.push(this.state.question.incorrect_answers[i]);
    }
    let randNum=Math.round(Math.random()* (incorrect_answers.length-1));
    let correct_answer=this.state.question.correct_answer;
    incorrect_answers.splice(randNum,0,correct_answer);
    return(

      <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>

        <h2><p>{this.state.question.category}:</p></h2>
        <h3><p>The question is {this.state.question.question}</p></h3>

          {incorrect_answers.map((answer,i) => <div key={i}><input name="somename" onChange={this.updateAnswer} type="radio" key={i} value={answer} />{answer} </div>)}
          <input type="submit" className="btn btn-success" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The idea is simple everytime a user submit the form I increment the currentQuestion state and pass the next question to QuestComp to display it ,the problem is the first time I have to click the submit button actually 2 times to go to the next question ,it just not render it and when i put console.log in the QuestComp render method to see what question it recieved ,actually it is the right one ,it just dont display it I dont know why ,so the first time I have to press 2 times the submit button to go to the next question ,after that it is working fine ,one press and renders the next question ,any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is related to the question state in `QuestComp` is out of sync with the question props passed from `Quiz`.

Just use the props passed from `Quiz` directly instead of setting the props to the state in `QuizComp`. Setting props to state like this is an anti-pattern and error prone.

So to solve this, just replace all your `this.state.question` in `QuestComp` with `this.props.question`.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous and it takes some time to complete. Your `this.props.onFormSubmit(e);` triggers right after and doesn't wait for it to  end.

Try using it this way:

```
this.setState({question : this.props.question},
() => this.props.onFormSubmit(e);
);
```

It should trigger after `setState` end and make your stuff work.

When you click submit for the first time you run `this.setState({ question: this.props.question });` with `this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuest]`.

The current value of `currentQuest` is `0` so it shows your question with `index = 0` again. `handleSubmit` increases it to `1` right after so every next go is good.

You need to increase that number before.

Comment: Not working ,the problem is only the first time ,I have to press 2 times the submit button to work ,after that it is working only with one press.

Comment: Expanded your answer more.